# What evidence shows that Moses wrote the Torah?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash, authorship

I asked this in hermeneutics.

Typical atheists think that Torah is written/compiled on Babylonian exile.

Christians and Jews believe that Torah was written by Moses or someone shortly after him, during the Exodus.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/when-is-torah-written-or-compiled

Then a guy in hermeneutics said that Jews in Elephantine do not have Torah suggesting that Torah was indeed written in the Babylonian exile.

What would be the evidence that support one or other theories?

If Jews believe that Moses wrote Torah, what are the evidences supporting that? Is there anything in the bible that Moses wrote Torah?

In fact, the end of Torah describes Moses' death.

> 7. Moses was one hundred and twenty years old when he died. His eye had not dimmed, nor had he lost his [natural] freshness.
> 8. And the sons of Israel wept for Moses in the plains of Moab for thirty days, and the days of weeping over the mourning for Moses came
>    to an end.

That uses past tenses. So Moses wrote Torah even 30 days after he was death?

Also the idea that no prophet greater than Moses suggests that it's unlikely to have been written during Moses time because at that time it would have been too obvious.

Moreover, Jews in Elephantine do not seem to have known Torah

> One should not interpret extra-biblical material through biblical
> data but thereverse, in this case making use of the Elephantine
> documents to interpret thePalestinian reality known from the Bible. 37
> 32 Porphyrius, De Abstinentia II 26. 33 In contrast to the
> votive-offering (Lev 7:16) and the peace-offering (Lev 19:5–6). 34
> GLAJJ 281 (4,1–2). 35 GLAJJ , vol. II, 1–4; Schäfer, Judeophobia ,
> 185–192. 36  Cf. Johnstone, ‘The Two Theological Versions’, 178. 37
> The opposite procedure can be seen for example in J. Mélèze
> Modrzejewski, The Jews of Egypt. From Ramses II to Emperor Hadrian
>
> , Edinburgh 1995, 37–43 (original French edition, 1991);Porten,
> Archives from Elephantine , 122–133. Łukasz Niesiołowski-Spanò
> PALAMEDES 2(2007) 48    We can explain the situation summarized above
> in two ways: 1) the Jewsat Elephantine did not know the biblical
> legislation, including the cultic calendar,because they remained cut
> off from Jerusalem and Yehud society (NB: they did notknow Pentateuch
> at all), 38 or 2) **they did not know this legislation because therewas
> no such legislation.The first of these possibilities looks
> implausible.** ...

http://www.academia.edu/717022/Passover_the_Jewish_cultic_calendar_and_the_Torah

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26783/472

Comment: So the evidence is that Torah said that Moses wrote Torah?

Comment: Actually, the question differ. Not sure what's being asked by the other guy. He seems to be a muslim evangelist or something?

Comment: How could jews in elephantine do not have Torah?

Comment: Hello Jim. Great question. I don't quite have an answer for you but just wondering this. Does anyone REALLY know for sure if everyone taking claim to authorship actually wrote the document? Take ghost writers for example. In our times, someone might file a law suit for plagiarism but I doubt if we will hear about even a fraction of the cases. Jim, are you aware of any specific people or individuals who claim that they wrote the Torah? The Talmud Most certainly was written in Babylon over the course of several hundred years by various writers. Is it possible that you are thinking of the Talmud?

Comment: Hi Jim! Chabad.org has a page with info regarding some parts of your question here>> http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380132/jewish/Written-in-Tears.htm  They quote(I think--there's a few layers..) the Baal Shem Tov quoting Rashi based on Talmud Baba Batra 15a regarding HaShem dictating the last parts of Torah to Moses, and bring up Malachi 3:22's "Remember the Torah of Moses, My servant" to show that Moses indeed wrote the whole Torah.

Comment: That Chabad story is even more insane. What? Moses write some garbled letter and the letter form itself? Even if it were true, Moses didn't write it then. God magically make the letter move by itself, which is a miracle. That means Torah is a changing document then? Also what happen with Torah written 2k years before world creation?

Comment: That's just the commentary on Rashi's original explanation. God dictated, Moses wrote. I never had a problem with it-if I was writing my autobiography & I was dying, I could write "And after all that stuff happened, Gary died."No big deal. Moses was a prophet, God told him what to write, everything before, during, and some things that would happen after his time. It's a matter of faith, of course. If you peruse the Prophets section, most, if not all wrote as if they were familiar with Torah and reference both Moses and the laws. Otherwise, how could they give the kings grief for breaking them?

Comment: Moses' name isn't mentioned a lot of times in the prophets, though he is in the books of history, psalms, etc.

Comment: That's all part of the "proof" Moses wrote the Torah.  Would Samuel and Nathan be giving Saul & David(& everyone else as necessary) grief for breaking laws if they weren't around then? Some form of the law code must have existed, with a tradition to back it up.  None of them ever said anything to anybody about breaking Freddy's Torah. The Psalms attributed to David took them and the tradition for granted...and that was only a few hundred years after they were written.

Comment: -1. This post haphazardly mixes a silly argument from the Jews in Elephantine with a tendentious indictment of the entire chumash based on the final verses of *D'varim*. As such, it is both unclear and not useful, IMO.

Comment: Jim, know that jews from elephantine where likely part of a military colony that was founded during the times of Menashe of the Judean Kingdom, who did all he could to eradicate the Torah: http://download.yutorah.org/2012/1053/Pesach_To-Go_-_5772_Dr_Katz.pdf

Comment: I think that elphantine thingy is just a strawman. The other arguments are valid though

Comment: I think a better question is do judaism believe that Moses wrote the torah? The answer is yes. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the evidence used in that article about Elephantine etc., it is very poor; the assumptions being made seem ridiculous to me. The fact that someone wants you to write to them at Pesach time doesn't mean they don't know what date you will celebrate it. The fact that people weren't keeping the Shabbat day doesn't mean no one knew about it. Sending people plain instructions about celebrating Pesach doesn't mean they couldn't access the information anywhere else, any more than when synagogues send out the same information in their email newsletters. And so on.

You can't know for sure from historical evidence if one person did write the Torah. What kind of evidence could you expect to survive for that? The only way to know it is if you decide that the Jewish testimony is valid and trustworthy about their own beliefs, and this kind of thing in particular.

(Edit:)
We can also learn from the way this is discussed in the Talmud, in Baba Batra 15a:

"The Master has said: Joshua wrote the book which bears his name and the last eight verses of the Pentateuch. This statement is in agreement with the authority who says that eight verses in the Torah were written by Joshua, as it has been taught: [It is written], So Moses the servant of the Lord died there. Now is it possible that Moses being dead could have written the words, 'Moses died there'? The truth is, however, that up to this point Moses wrote, from this point Joshua wrote. This is the opinion of R. Judah, or, according to others, of R. Nehemiah. Said R. Simeon to him: Can [we imagine the] scroll of the Law being short of one word, and is it not written, Take this book of the Law? No; what we must say is that up to this point the Holy One, blessed be He, dictated and Moses repeated and wrote, and from this point God dictated and Moses wrote with tears..."

So- can you see how even the rabbis debated about part of this question? I'm no expert in this, but here is my understanding. The people who said Moses wrote the whole thing did so on the basis of their general understanding of Judaism, Torah and truth. If they were wrong about this minor detail it doesn't destroy Judaism at all. but many Jews agree with the authority of this speculation and go by it.

(Keep in mind that some historical ideas seem to have been speculation/opinions, while other things are believed to be real things remembered through history... such as the giving of the Torah.)

Comment: You're right. I didn't see it through. But then again, very few jews saw Moses actually writing it out either. We know what we are told. What's unique about jews is that for the last 2k years they don't have the power to manipulate public info (and hence more credible). But 3k years ago? Who knows.

Comment: I added an edit in my answer to address that thought. It is my own personal understanding.

Comment: North Korean believe there are double rainbow during the birth of their president. I wonder if jews 5k years ago had more access to accurate information than contemporary north korean.

Comment: Why are you interested in Judaism to begin with? Why does it catch your attention so that you want to find out if it's true, instead of just ignoring it along with the other religions?

Comment: Jim - Jews 10 minutes ago have more access to accurate information than contemporary North KoreanS.

Comment: Right! But I think he means that propaganda, when wholeheartedly accepted for one reason or another, can allow strange and unfounded beliefs into the mix. Obviously the claims and situations are different though, and the Jewish claim is a much bigger one, much less easy to simply enter the national consciousness.

Comment: I don't mean jews 10 minutes ago. I mean jews 5k years ago. Those who disagree, like Korah, are killed right? Maybe not everyone in Israel at that time agree with with "miracle". Maybe the sea wasn't split. Those who disagree were killed like in North Korean. Why I want to know about judaism? Well, your sister religions, Islam and Christianity is a huge phenomena that influence the world. Not to mention I am curious if that God really exist or not.

Comment: Islam is not "questionable" ;). As for christianity, I've been there done that already. It's amazing how christians would stretch the bible to fit their agenda. I am aware that early christians have varying opinions and the final form we have now is a result of a vote and killing of those who disagree. I am also well aware that they're not going to see it as it really is.

Comment: Look, let me think about that for a while. I also ask a lot about buddhism. But they don't have their stackexchange. Also it's kind of hard to question a religion that doesn't have faith and actually encourage people to keep questioning like Buddhism. 30% of American Buddhist are jews by the way. And 50% of jews are atheists.

Comment: Jewish testimony is valid and trustworthy about their own beliefs, and this kind of thing in particular. - I agree. That being said, how do I know that jewish' testimony are more credible than say chinese, indians, babylonians, all must have claimed many miracles their supposed deity have done. Also torah wrote pharaoh rather than identifying the pharaoh. Perhaps, whoever wrote the torah, didn't know who the pharaoh was. Perhaps it's written much latter.

Comment: Even north korean may have access to more information than jews 5k years ago and that's the point. Okay, may be not north korean. This age is called information age for a reason. Even with this much information, we still have fairy tales like global warming, women trafficking, etc that people believe in.

Comment: Note: I just listened again to Rabbi Berel Wein about the Jews of Elephantine. They had **halachic** questions and therefore wrote to the main halachic authorities of their day. They were asking about what date Pesach would be (not to be answered on Pesach). They were asking to have the current and future year calendars sent to them. They were a group of Jewish mercenary soldiers assigned (for life) to an isolated outpost and had not been taught the Torah, nor did they have people who could teach them. The tape is part of Rabbi Wein's history series in the group of tapes about the Chashmonaim.